# how to avoid copying when using std::transform_reduce(par,...)

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I would like to use `std::transform_reduce` to generate complex information from a collection of objects. That means that one information object is generated per source object in the collection (`transform`) and then all these information objects are reduced into one (`reduce`). As the information object is quite large, I would like to **avoid copying** along the way as much as possible. A quick test shows that `seq` and `par` execution differ already at compilation stage when it comes to this aspect.

When using `seq` execution, the following call to `transform_reduce` seems to provoke few copies:

```
using namespace std;
Inte sum = transform_reduce( execution::seq, v.begin(), v.end(), Inte{0},
                             [](Inte &a,Inte const &b) /*-> Inte*/ { a.combine(b); return move(a); },
                             [](int i){ return Inte{i}; }  );
cout << "sum is " << sum.I << "\n";
```

*(pls find the simple demonstration object `Inte` below)*

When changing execution to `par`, this call no longer compiles, i.e. passing the first arg to the `binary_op` by reference is not accepted anymore. I have to change to:

```
using namespace std;
Inte sum = transform_reduce( execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), Inte{0},
                             [](Inte a,Inte const &b) /*-> Inte*/ { a.combine(b); return a; },
                             [](int i){ return Inte{i}; }  );
cout << "sum is " << sum.I << "\n";
```

Now again, this version means a lot more copying of `Inte`s along the computation.

**How can this copying be minimised when executing in `par`?**

The code of the example object follows here. Pls note that this is an example only, to save space here. Of course this example only holds an integer, which would reduce the above problem to something trivial. But the real object for the problem at hand holds a few vectors and maps to aggregate information.

**Update:** The following now shows the complete example in one place (as requested in the comments). This version compiles and runs. To show the error, the execution parameter in the first call has to be changed from `seq` to `par`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>
using namespace std;

class Inte
{
public:
    Inte( int i ) :  I(i) {
        cout << string{"construct "}.append(to_string(I)).append("\n");
    }
    Inte( Inte const &i ) :  I(i.I) {
        cout << string{"copy-const "}.append(to_string(I)).append("\n");
    }
    Inte( Inte &&i ) :  I(i.I) {
        i.I = -1;
        cout << string{"move-const "}.append(to_string(I)).append("\n");
    }
    Inte &operator=( Inte const &i ) {
        I = i.I;
        cout << string{"copy "}.append(to_string(I)).append("\n");
        return *this;
    }
    Inte &operator=( Inte &&i ) {
        I = i.I;
        i.I = -2;
        cout << string{"move "}.append(to_string(I)).append("\n");
        return *this;
    }
    void combine( Inte const &i ) {
        I += i.I;;
        cout << string{"combine to "}.append(to_string(I)).append("\n");
    }
    int I{};
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[]) {
    vector<int> v{1,10,100};
    cout << "vector constructed\n";
    Inte sun = transform_reduce( execution::seq, v.begin(), v.end(), Inte{0},
                                 [](Inte &a,Inte const &b) /*-> Inte*/ { a.combine(b); return move(a); },
                                 [](int i){ return Inte{i}; }  );
    cout << "sun is " << sun.I << "\n";
    Inte suo = transform_reduce( execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), Inte{0},
                                 [](Inte a,Inte const &b) /*-> Inte*/ { a.combine(b); return a; },
                                 [](int i){ return Inte{i}; }  );
    cout << "suo is " << suo.I << "\n";
}
```

The compilation normally is controlled by the IDE, but the compiler statement used is this (a bit shortened but still showing the behaviour; so a minimal example):

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++1z -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC  -o main.o ../demos/main.cpp
```

When changing the execution parameter to `par`, this is compilation error (g++ version: 10.2.0):

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/parallel_backend.h:16,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/algorithm_impl.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/glue_execution_defs.h:50,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/execution:32,
                 from ../demos/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h: In instantiation of ‘void __pstl::__par_backend::__par_trans_red_body<_Index, _Up, _Tp, _Cp, _Rp>::operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<Index>&) [with _Index = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Up = __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >)>; _Tp = Inte; _Cp = main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>; _Rp = __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte)>]’:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_reduce.h:150:47:   required from ‘void tbb::interface9::internal::start_reduce<Range, Body, Partitioner>::run_body(Range&) [with Range = tbb::blocked_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >; Body = __pstl::__par_backend::__par_trans_red_body<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >)>, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte)> >; Partitioner = const tbb::auto_partitioner]’
/usr/include/tbb/partitioner.h:423:27:   required from ‘void tbb::interface9::internal::dynamic_grainsize_mode<Mode>::work_balance(StartType&, Range&) [with StartType = tbb::interface9::internal::start_reduce<tbb::blocked_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >, __pstl::__par_backend::__par_trans_red_body<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >)>, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte)> >, const tbb::auto_partitioner>; Range = tbb::blocked_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >; Mode = tbb::interface9::internal::adaptive_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type>]’
/usr/include/tbb/partitioner.h:256:28:   required from ‘void tbb::interface9::internal::partition_type_base<Partition>::execute(StartType&, Range&) [with StartType = tbb::interface9::internal::start_reduce<tbb::blocked_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >, __pstl::__par_backend::__par_trans_red_body<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >)>, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte)> >, const tbb::auto_partitioner>; Range = tbb::blocked_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >; Partition = tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type]’
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_reduce.h:190:29:   required from ‘tbb::task* tbb::interface9::internal::start_reduce<Range, Body, Partitioner>::execute() [with Range = tbb::blocked_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >; Body = __pstl::__par_backend::__par_trans_red_body<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >)>, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, __pstl::__internal::__pattern_transform_reduce<const __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte, main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >::<lambda()>::<lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, Inte)> >; Partitioner = const tbb::auto_partitioner]’
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_reduce.h:181:11:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:177:31: error: no match for call to ‘(main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>) (Inte, Inte)’
  177 |                 _Tp(_M_combine(_M_u(__i), _M_u(__i + 1))); // The condition i+1 < j is provided by the grain size of 3
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:177:31: note: candidate: ‘Inte (*)(Inte&, const Inte&)’ (conversion)
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:177:31: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:177:36: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Inte&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Inte’
  177 |                 _Tp(_M_combine(_M_u(__i), _M_u(__i + 1))); // The condition i+1 < j is provided by the grain size of 3
      |                                ~~~~^~~~~
../demos/main.cpp:41:34: note: candidate: ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda(Inte&, const Inte&)>’ (near match)
   41 |                                  [](Inte &a,Inte const &b) /*-> Inte*/ { a.combine(b); return move(a); },
      |                                  ^
../demos/main.cpp:41:34: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/parallel_backend.h:16,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/algorithm_impl.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/glue_execution_defs.h:50,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/execution:32,
                 from ../demos/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:177:36: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Inte&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Inte’
  177 |                 _Tp(_M_combine(_M_u(__i), _M_u(__i + 1))); // The condition i+1 < j is provided by the grain size of 3
      |                                ~~~~^~~~~
```

**Update 2:** When looking at the output of the working (that is second) par version only, there's a copy-const call in front of any combine:

```
vector constructed
construct 0
copy-const 0
copy-const 0
copy-const 0
copy-const 0
copy-const 0
copy-const 0
construct 1
copy-const 0
combine to 1
move-const 1
move 1
construct 10
copy-const 1
combine to 11
move-const 11
move 11
construct 100
copy-const 11
combine to 111
move-const 111
move 111
move-const 111
move 111
copy-const 111
suo is 111
```

Comment: could you give a [mcve], including the command you use for compilation and please give your compiler errors.

Comment: p.s. simply using `std::cout << "construct " << I << '\n';` saves a lot of unnecessary creation of temporary objects.

Comment: [not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/eb9Yjd)....

Comment: I tried to reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/KMqc7f. I got some initial copies, but these I believe are necessary since the initial value needs to be distributed to all threads. Note that no other value is copied. The binary op works with both reference parameters well.

Comment: But agree that those copies are weird, since the initial value needs to be used only once: https://godbolt.org/z/YbbP3z. So don't understand why it is copied, and as you say, it is with GCC even for `seq` execution policy. Moreover, without execution policy argument, there are no copies at all: https://godbolt.org/z/Yb4E3h.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm sorry, I considered the information given to be an m.r.e - especially minimal in the sense of saving space here. Of course, stating the exact compiler error helps. I updated the question to include all.

Comment: @JHBonarius Thanks for trying to reproduce. That means, the reference/move version compiles on godbolt even as par!? Strange.   (@Daniel-langr: Your version uses a `+` in the lamda, which won't work for my original problem, as explained above.)

Comment: Note that libstdc++ does not have its own parallel version of std algorithms with GCC 10. It uses Intel TBB as a backend, which may be seen also from your compilation error. Your question is then basically related to TBB. I am not sure whether TBB is C++ Standard compliant with its parallel algorithms.

Comment: Regarding your update 2: look at your code... your removed the `move(a)`.

Comment: @JHBonarius That move is redundant (as per compiler warning) when the arg is not passed by ref (which, in turn, cannot as it wouldn't compile here). With the redundant move added, the output doesn't change.

Comment: @DanielLangr You are right. I didn't spot the reference to tbb in the error message. TBB is used here, of course. Might this justify opening an issue with gnu libstdc++ (as gnu decided to use tbb here)?

Comment: Yes, I also though the move was redundant, as per RVO. However, just try to put it there and see the change in behavior. Very curious.

Comment: @JHBonarius There's no change in behaviour, sorry (without also passing by ref). Thanks for hinting to godbolt (didn't know it). Testing there (in-/excluding TBB) seems to support Daniels point that TBB plays a role here.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Note the whole `transform_reduce` can be replaced by a `reduce` like this: `auto sum = std::reduce( std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), Inte{0},
                             [](auto&& a,auto&& b) { a.combine(b); return std::move(a); }  );`

Answer (score 0):

Studying the helpful comments and conducting further research lead to the insight that, indeed, the `binary_op` (the reduce) is not correct this way. Thus the compiler error is justified.

(For me) It's hard to read this prerequisite out of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce , but

```
binary_op   -   binary FunctionObject that will be applied in unspecified order to the results of unary_op, the results of other binary_op and init.
```

means (i.a.) that `binary_op` may be presented with `rvalues` as well as with `lvalues`.
As `rvalues` cannot bind to (non-`const`) `lvalue` references, and the `a` parameter cannot be `const` in my case. the correct `binary_op` must use a "universal" reference for a:

```
[](auto &&a,Inte const &b) /*-> Inte*/ { a.combine(b); return forward<Inte>(a); }
```

Executing this version with policy `par` still executes more copies than execution with `seq`: For a vector with `n` elements it is around `n*.005` copy constructs (as opposed to `2` with `seq`). Also there are more moves: around `n*1.0025` calls to move constructors (`seq`: `n+1`), similar for move assignments. (`n=500000` for this example, 4 threads)